# Next.js + Typescript: where to put logic files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js project with Typescript.

I have a file with configurations for external API and function and types that I am exporting.

When I import a type or a function.

```js
import type { Post } from "@/utils/airtable";
or
import { savePost } from "@/utils/airtable";
```

I get this error from typescript.

> Cannot find module '@/utils/airtable' or its corresponding type declarations.

I have no idea why I get that message.

Here is part of my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/api/*": ["/pages/api/*"],
            "@/utils/*": ["/utils/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried without the paths and @ symbol. Same error occurred

Comment: Can you try removing leading slash from `/utils` (and `/pages...`)?

Comment: @brc-dd same behaviour as before.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?